# Chart.js pie get value from JSON

Tags: javascript, php

I have `JSON` data in `PHP` variable, i want to show that data in `chart.js pie` 
It is currently static i want to read the data from the json that is in the variable
my PHP code
this convert array to json and put to variable

```
$datajson = json_encode($data);
```

my javascript code
By default get value static

```
var p_config = {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [
                '20',
                '40',
                '30',
            ],
            backgroundColor: [
                window.chartColors.red,
                window.chartColors.orange,
                window.chartColors.yellow,
            ],
            label: 'Dataset 1'
        }],
        labels: [
            "rize",
            "Maize",
            "Alfalfa",
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            labels: {
                fontColor: 'black',
            }
        },
        tooltips: {
            fontColor: 'black',
        }
    }
};

window.onload = function() {
    var p_ctx = document.getElementById("product").getContext("2d");
    window.myPie = new Chart(p_ctx, p_config);
};
```

Comment: Add your json data as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to fill the value for `data` in JavaScript with the data from `$data` in PHP and your `$data` has the same structure with `datasets` and `labels`. Then you're only missing the link between the two.

```
var data = <?=json_encode($data)?>;
var p_config = {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            labels: {
                fontColor: 'black',
            }
        },
        tooltips: {
            fontColor: 'black',
        }
    }
};
```